# How to get object space in a shader from an UI Image (DisableBatching does not seem to work)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, shader

I have a very simple scene with an image and a canvas (its parent).
The image has a shader on it, all it does that it multiplies the vertex.x by 2 (while in object space) before translating it into clip space.
The result is the following : 
[image]

It seems like that the image used the canvas's object space instead of its own for the multiplication.

The whole shader looks like this :
[image]

I tried to use the tag "DisableBatching" = "True" to preserve the object space of the image in the shader, but with no success. Even tried with different unity versions. (yes im getting desperate here:D)

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Comment: I don't really see what you want to achieve with this shader. Do you want to stratch the image? As it works now the shader seems to work with the PosX of the `RectTransform` as input. You could try creating a parent-object for the image, so the PosX and PosY of the `RectTransform` are always 0.

Comment: yes, well the final effect i was going for was not the one i presented here, i just figured this way it was easier to explain the problem i was running into.
but tbh, as you said, it was not the best task to handle on the GPU, so i just moved it to c# side, and modified the vertexstream instead:)

Answer (score 1):

The UI system's vertex data is already provided relative to the screen, with (0, 0) in the center and - in my experience - the upper right corner being (screen.width/2, screen.height/2). This might however change depending on platforms or your canvas setup.

This is the behaviour you are seing here, the x coordinate is scaled by 2 relative to the center of your canvas (which would most likely be the extend of your screen in the game view).

There is no "object space" per-se, you would need to pass additional data (i.e. in a texture coordinate) depending on your needs.

Comment: Thx. This is really helpful for me. I was struggle with why vertex doesn't modifying in UI systems.